# How to show the image of custom content type in drupal page.tpl.php?

Tags: drupal

I just created a custom content type in drupal7 and I want to manage the image of that content in my template. `<?php print $content; ?>` displays all the field of that content. But I just want to show the image only.How can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must somehow get node id of node that contains that picture (hard-code it or something). Then use node_load() function to load whole node - image field will be one of available fields in loaded node object. Use print_r or something to check out available fields, so you can construct exact code, but it should be something like this:

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$picture_uri = $node->field_myimagefield['und'][0]['uri'];

// To get image path in specific image style you created:
$picture_style_path = image_style_url('style_name', picture_uri); 

// To get original image path
$picture_original_path = file_create_url($picture_uri);
```

Then you can directly print picture path into img html tag...

But, are you sure that you are using right template file? If you want template just for your content type you should use node, not page template (which is wrapper for node template).

Comment: I am new to drupal. I just make page.tpl.php and try to show the image using above code. But the image did not display.Can you refer a good example for theme integration in drupal?

Comment: Here is page explaining template naming: https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656

But google for it...there are a lot of articles explaining templating in Drupal.
Basically, you have templates one inside another... So, most outer is html.tpl.php and then inside is page.tpl.php . Usually (but not necessary) they are common for all pages. Then, inside page you have node templates. Usually you have different node template for every content type you created. Check out the page I posted above to see how to name template files. And don't forget to clear the cache after adding new one!

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Drupal-7-Theme also a good guideline to make a Drupal template